# Prediction with large inputs and outputs

Tags: regression, predictive-models, dataset, torch

Being a total newbie with machine learning, I thought I would seek your advice on a problem of mine. I'm looking for any leads, starting points ans help you could provide me.

I'm looking to predict really large vectors of unique values, knowing as input smaller input vectors. 
The idea would be:

dataset: vectors ranging from 50K to 600K, a lot of them

what we want: give the algorithm part of these vectors (maybe something like 10K) and predict the rest of the vector. The size of the output vector would be 600K as it is the all dataset, 1 if it will exist in the predicted vector, 0 if it won't be in it.

We know those vectors and could compare the prediction against them to improve the algorithm.

This is where I'm stuck for now. Where to start? I was looking maybe into Multi class Linear Regression. Could I use some kind of Neural Network?

I'm also not sure what kind of problem it, if it is part of classification problems? Is the problem too ambitious in terms of output sizing?

I'm using torch7 for now, but can't manage to find any solution or lead on what to use.

Thanks a lot.